# On AJAX refresh all JavaScript events are breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an AJAX call to replace everything below the header and everything above the footer of a the page when the user clicks a filter link.

The problem is that after the AJAX event, all the JavaScript events bound to the various DOM elements break. This makes sense as those were bound on a much lower module level example

```
$(".innerDiv").on("click",function(){doSomething();}
```

and by replacing the content of the parent container these events are no longer bound.

What is the correct way of handling this problem? I could add the event listener to a much higher level e.g

```
$(document).on("click",".innerDiv",function(){doSomething();}
```

But this would have the same inefficiencies and issues for which the live() function in jQuery was deprecated.

The other solution that I have found suggested is to rebind the events after the AJAX call. The problem is that this is a fairly complex page I am dealing with, and it contains a lot of JavaScript modules each of which have their own bindings. How would I keep track of every event that gets binded? Is there any way of accessing this information from within jQuery? should i be maintaining my own datastructure of all elements which have events bound to them?

Also would I need to unbind events using the "off()" function before making the AJAX  request?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The `$(document).on("click",".innerDiv",handler)` is more efficient than `.live` was, though you can make it even more efficient by using an element farther down the tree, such as a parent of `.innerDiv` that doesn't get replaced with ajax. The alternative is to re-bind the event every time the refresh happens.

Comment: suggestion: Instead of removing, elements why not hide the old contend and add new one on top of it?

Comment: There should be no reason to unbind events in this scenario.

Comment: Hi Keven, why would I not need to unbind events. Some of the stuff I read suggested that the events bound to the elements which get replaced by the ajax call are still stored in some jquery event queue. Is that not the case?

Comment: @CodeMonkeyB Correct, if you .remove() an elemnt or remove it with any other jQuery method (even .html("")) the events are automatically unbound.

Comment: @KevinB does the unbinding also hold true for methods such as replaceWith()? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery could use beforeSend http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to unbind the events